# FFMPEG - Flaky internet for streaming, fallback stream or image

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I am using NGINX to receive rtmp and output to hls.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        ...
        application rtmp {
            live on;
            ...
            exec ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/rtmp/$name -threads 1 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:a 64k -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -g 10 -b:v 300K -s 480x240 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/hls/$name;
        }
        application hls {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My stream comes from Flash Media Live Encoder.  But sometimes I have flaky internet because my connection comes from mobile.  Sometimes internet drops for 3-5 seconds every 5 minutes.  But this is enough to disrupt the stream.  Is it possible for me to make it run continuously even when my FMLE is disconnected?

I am thinking of executing an FFMPEG from the server box to stream continuously an image as a fallback when FMLE is disconnected, then combine the 2 RTMP streams.  Perhaps favoring the one from FMLE if available, and the other as fallback.  But I am not sure how to combine using FFMPEG.

Or is there another hack I can try?